# Jetty 7 - Does it perform gzip compression by default

Tags: jetty, gzip

I have a web application built on google's GWT framework. I was planning on setting up the Jetty GzipFilter in order to make the response compressed. Here, i noticed, after checking on firebug and TCP mon that even without the filter, the responses are gzipped.

I checked the xml configuration files in jetty and could not find any default gzip filter defined anywhere. Can you please tell me if Jetty-7 does gzip compression by default?

I'm using jetty version 7.4.5. 
If additional information is required, please let me know and I shall provide.

Comment: I think GWT does that for you.. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/02nDfzqLc-Q

Comment: Thank you. Can you please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT does response compression for you... https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/02nDfzqLc-Q